# confusion over Rspec association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, rspec-rails

I am new to Rspec, but have got stuck on something thats probably fairly basic.

In one of my specs, i have the following (condensed):

```
require 'rails_helper'

RSpec.describe Sophead, type: :model do
  let(:sophead) { FactoryGirl.create(:sophead) }
  let(:od) { FactoryGirl.create(:od) }
  let(:active_od_issue) { FactoryGirl.create(:od_issue, active:true)}
  describe "#issue_flag?"  do
    it "should return true if there is an active od issue" do
      od.update!(sophead_id: sophead.id)
      active_od_issue.update!(od_id:od.id)
      puts "sophead.id = #{sophead.id}"
      puts "od.id = #{od.id}"
      puts "od.sophead.id = #{od.sophead.id}"
      puts "Sophead.ods.count = #{sophead.ods.count}"
      puts "Sophead.ods.first.id = #{sophead.ods.first.id}"
      expect(sophead.issue_flag?).to be true
    end
  end
end
```

Sophead has many ods

Running the spec fails and prints the following:

```
    Sophead
  #issue_flag?
sophead.id = 2882
od.id = 1344
od.sophead.id = 2882
Sophead.ods.count = 1
    should return true if there is an active od issue (FAILED - 1)

Failures:

  1) Sophead#issue_flag? should return true if there is an active od issue
     Failure/Error: puts "Sophead.ods.first.id = #{sophead.ods.first.id}"

     NoMethodError:
       undefined method `id' for nil:NilClass
     # ./spec/models/untitled_spec.rb:17:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'

Finished in 2.34 seconds (files took 5.95 seconds to load)
1 example, 1 failure
```

I don't understand how Sophead.ods.count = 1 but Sophead.ods.first is nil
How can this be?

Factory for Od:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :od do
    created_at "2018-09-19 11:58:58"
    updated_at "2018-09-19 11:58:58"
    status "Open"
    number_packages nil
    number_loose_lengths nil
    packed false
    picker_id nil
    packer_id nil
    picked false
    pick_list false
    label_type "Own van"
    tracking_number nil
    courier_latest_status nil
    priority 4
    packed_weight nil
    on_hold false
    photo nil
    pod nil
    picked_at nil
    packed_at nil
    despatched_at nil
    issue_flag false
    pod_byte_array nil
    photo_byte_array nil
    delivered false
    despatched false
    pick_started_at nil
    pack_started_at nil
    number_labels nil
    last_latitude 51.516185
    last_longitude 0.101993
    drop_number 0
    eta nil
    run_id 54
    direct false
    due_by "2018-09-19 13:00:00"
    delivery_failed false
    printing false
    oversize false
    trackpod false
    sales_order "312790"
    inv_name "A. Company & Sons"
    del_postcode "NW6 2HL"
    route
    run
    sophead
  end
end
```

Factory for Sophead:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :sophead do
    sysuser
    sales_order "1234567"
    carriage 10.52
    contactname "John Smith"
    date_amended Date.today
    del_add1 "Parkhall Trading Estate"
    del_add2 "40 Martel Road"
    del_city "London"
    del_country "UK"
    del_county "London"
    del_name "Jim Smith"
    del_postcode "SE21 8EN"
    delivery_notes "this is a delivery note"
    due_date Date.tomorrow
    flag_status 2
    salesman 17
    order_date Date.yesterday
    order_notes "this is an order note"
    order_type "O"
    order_value 50.92
    user_created 33
    flag_delete 0
    cost 20.50
    area 51
    # issue_flag false
    issue_desc nil
  end
end
```

Thanks.

Comment: check the class of Sophead.ods

Comment: Sophead.ods.class = Od::ActiveRecord_Associations_CollectionProxy

Comment: keep binding.pry and check what data is comming in sophead.ods and check sophead.ods.first

Comment: @SumanthMadishetty pry(#<RSpec::ExampleGroups::Sophead::IssueFlag>)> sophead.ods
=> []    

pry(#<RSpec::ExampleGroups::Sophead::IssueFlag>)> sophead.ods.first
=> nil      

pry(#<RSpec::ExampleGroups::Sophead::IssueFlag>)> sophead.ods.count
=> 1
pry(#<RSpec::ExampleGroups::Sophead::IssueFlag>)> od.sophead.id
=> 3000

Comment: You are getting an empty array in the object sophead.ods so please check the data of sopheads and check if valid data is comming or not and also try to inlcude the factory file in your question

Comment: and try to add reload! after the update line in case if the instance is not getting updated with  new values.. to check check the data of od and sophead before and after update

Comment: @SumanthMadishetty I have updated my question to show the 2 factories.  reload! after update does not make any difference.  FactoryGirl.create(:od) and FactoryGirl.create(:sophead) both create valid objects.

Comment: It is sophead you're reloading, right?  Just before the `puts` you should try `sophead.reload`

Comment: @SteveTurczyn - Thanks!  That fixes it, but why is that needed and is there any way to do this automatically?

Comment: Yes, it's the way you assigned the 'od'  Doing `od.update!(sophead_id: sophead.id)` rails doesn't actually know that the relationship has changed so it doesn't reload the relationship.  Had you done `sophead.ods << od` it would've assigned the id for you AND it would've updated the sophead relationship.

Comment: ... it's generally better to let rails do the foreign key assignments.  Someday if the relationship between `od` and `sophead` changes (maybe you implement a `join` table, for example) the `<<` code continues to work, whereas your code would fail.

Answer (score 0):

Big thanks to @SteveTurczyn for getting to the bottom of this.  As he says, instead of updating the parent_id on the child object using:

`od.update!(sophead_id: sophead.id)`

associate the child object with the parent

`sophead.ods << od`

so that rails knows the relationship has changed.